# Why does M101 search string have RA variable from 0 to 360 and Dec variable from -90 to +90 in the Hubble Legacy Archive?

Tags: galaxy, coordinate, hubble-telescope

I was scraping some images off the Hubble Legacy Archive and I found that searching M101 with RA in range 0-360 and Dec in range -90 to +90 yields results. Now I understand that Messier 101 galaxy has the co-ordinates RA 14h 3m 13s | Dec +54° 20′ 57″.

So what images am I getting if HLA has images for M101  RA = 52.000000  Dec = -13.000000  r = 1  [03:28:00.000 -13:00:00.00]

Could someone explain what's going on?

[image]

Comment: Did you do any other searches, or perhaps an advanced search, before this?  I can’t reproduce the problem.

Comment: I'm inserting the RA and dec values directly into the url

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that somehow that string “M101” got inserted into the search box but has nothing to do with your query results.   For example, if you click the “M101” link right below the box it will insert that into the search box without changing your search results until you click “Search”.

The images shown in your search output are labeled with their object names, RCS0327-1326.

If you’re still getting odd results, the editing your question to show your full URL from your query would be helpful.

Comment: Okay, I'll check on this